# Python SIP extension for Qt C++: how to handle QVector signal argument

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, python-sip

I'm new to Python/SIP and need to create a Python binding for a Qt/C++ library using it.

The class header looks like this:

```
class MyClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
    signals:
        void message(QString msg);
        void data(QVector<quint16> *data);
    ...
};
```

This is the according SIP specification file:

```
%Module myclassPy
%Import QtCore/QtCoremod.sip

class MyClass : public QObject
{
%TypeHeaderCode
#include "myclass.h"
%End
    ...
    signals:
        void message(QString msg);
        void data(QVector<quint16> *data);
};
```

Importing the Python module and connecting the `message` signal to a Python slot (using PyQt5) work like a charm.
However, connecting the `data` signal doesn't work: `TypeError: C++ type 'QVector<quint16>' is not supported as a signal argument type`.

So I need to convert the QVector (pointer) argument of the signal to a Python object (probably a list).
What is the best way to do this with SIP?
Do I need to specify a new signal with a Python type argument?

I already tried using a `%MappedType QVector<quint16>` definition to convert it to a Python list but that didn't work (same TypeError as above in Python).

Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE - I kind of found a solution/workaround:

The `data(QVector<quint16> *data)` signal got replaced by a signal without argument, e.g. `dataAvailable()`. Then a public method like `QVector<quint16> *getData()` is added to transfer the data. The `%MappedType QVector<quint16>` definition is kept (as I already tried it before) and converts the return type to a Python `PyObject *`. However, this works with the return value of the `getData()` method but not with signal arguments.

In Python, just connect the signal `dataAvailable()` to a slot and call `getData()` from within this slot.

Therefore the data has to be buffered somewhere within `MyClass`.